# Fastest SQL & HQL Query for two tables

Tags: sql, oracle, hibernate, hql

Table1: Columns A, B, C
Table2: Columns A, B, C

Table 2 is a copy of Table 1 with different data. Assume all columns to be varchar

Looking for a single efficient query  which can fetch:

- Columns A, B, C from Table1
- Additional Rows from Table2 where values of Table2.A are not present in Table1.A

Any differences between the Oracle SQL & HQL for the same query will be appreciated.

I'm fiddling with Joins, Unions & Minus but not able to get the correct combination.

Comment: Try intersect, Minus, Except

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SQL:**

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1
UNION ALL
SELECT *
FROM Table2 T2
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT 'X' FROM Table1 T1
    WHERE T1.A = T2.A
)
```

**HQL:**

You must execute two different query an discard the element by Table2 result in a Java loop because in HQL doesn't exist UNION command.

Alternatatively you can write the first query for Table1 and the second query must have a not in clause to discard Table1 A field.

Solution 1:

Query 1:

```
SELECT * FROM Table1
```

Query 2:
    SELECT * FROM Table2

and then you apply a discard loop in Java code

Solution 2:

Query 1:

```
SELECT * FROM Table1
```

Query 2:

```
SELECT * FROM Table2 WHERE Table2.A not in (SELECT Table1.A from Table1)
```

Answer (score 1):

This query returns all rows in `table1`, plus all rows in `table2` which does not exist in `table1`, given that column `a` is the common key.

```
select a,b,c
  from table1
 union 
   all
select a,b,c
  from table2
 where a not in(select a from table1);
```

There may be different options available depending on the relative sizes of table1 and table2 and the expected overlap.

Comment: Thanks @Ronnis. The query was bang on.
But selected Joe Taras' answer as it was a viable solution in HQL.